# Use TFS 2013 to version Windows Store App Builds

Tags: c#, windows, tfs, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

We are using TFS 2013 to manage our source code for a Windows Store app. Unfortunately, it looks like we have to change the version number manually. This is tedious and easy to forget. If we use the wrong build twice, we have to take extra steps to deploy. Is there a way to set version numbers when the Build server builds?

Comment: That does not apply for Windows Runtime (Windows Store) applications from what I have gathered. I will give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: @DanielMann It is not working for Windows Store applications.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong! Respectfully retracted. :)

Comment: The issue is not incrementing in Visual Studio. That works fine. The issue is our builds are not done in Visual Studio, they are being done by our TFS 2013 server. Is there a way to perform this that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This will modify the version number in the appmanifest. I'm not sure of the source, if anyone would post the source, I will add this to this comment.

This is a powershell script that I added to the project source control and set it to run pre-build. This worked like a charm for each build for me. This is exactly what I wanted it to do.

```
# get the build number, we assume the format is Myproject.Main.CI_1.0.0.18290
# where the version is set using the TFSVersion custom build activity (see other posts)
$buildnum = $env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER.Split('_')[1]
# get the manifest file paths
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY -Filter "Package.appxmanifest" -Recurse
foreach ($filepath in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Updating the Store App Package '$filepath' to version ' $buildnum '"
    # update the identity value
    $XMLfile=NEW-OBJECT XML
    $XMLfile.Load($filepath.Fullname)
    $XMLFile.Package.Identity.Version=$buildnum
    # set the file as read write
    Set-ItemProperty $filepath.Fullname -name IsReadOnly -value $false
    $XMLFile.save($filepath.Fullname)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute a PowerShell pre-build on the build server to update the build number. There is an example script as part of the TFS Community Build Tools.

https://curah.microsoft.com/8047/run-scripts-in-your-team-foundation-build-process

Look for ApplyVersionToAssemblies.ps1. You will have to customise to update any manafest files you need...